# Variable JavaScript en URL no funciona

Tags: javascript

resulta que tengo una pagina que genera un link en un acortador y el siguiente script lo que hace es que si entran desde un movil o tableta redifige segun el explorador, cuando ingreso a la url como escritorio imprime la variablebn pero si uso el mismo link y hago mi explorador como si fuese desde movil se pierde la varible y no imprime " + cuatro + " y en la url me sale undifined o sea en https://ejemplo-subdominio-undifined-dominio.com/test.html

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
if (screen.width <= 699) {
document.location = "https://ejemplo-subdominio- " + cuatro + " -dominio.com/test.html" + window.location.search
var uno =new String(window.atob(llegaron[1])); //Regreso
var dos =new String(window.atob(llegaron[2])); //UrlFin
var tres = (llegaron[3]); //Usuario
var cuatro =new String(window.atob(llegaron[4])); //Identificador
var cinco =new String(window.atob(llegaron[5]));  //Provedor
var seis =new String(window.atob(llegaron[6]));  //Provedor
var regreso = uno; //Regreso
var urlfin = dos;  //UrlFin
var idfb = tres; //Usuario
var detector = cuatro; //identifier
var lang = cinco;  //Provedo
var identifier = seis; //identifier
var enblanco = window.location.href; //En Blanco
var myString = new String(window.location.href);
var myArray = myString.split('*');
var regreso = myArray[1];
var urlfin = myArray[2];
var email = myArray[3];
var detector = myArray[4];
}
//-->
</script>
```

Comment: Es porque la variable `cuatro` se tiene que definir antes de usarla y en tu caso primero la usas y después la declaras.

Comment: me podrias decir basado en el cdigo como lo implementarias tu? muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0):

La variable `cuatro` debe definirse antes de usarla. Por esa razón la línea del `document.location = ...` debe ir después de la declaración de la variable `cuatro`.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

if (screen.width <= 699) {

var uno =new String(window.atob(llegaron[1])); //Regreso
var dos =new String(window.atob(llegaron[2])); //UrlFin
var tres = (llegaron[3]); //Usuario
var cuatro =new String(window.atob(llegaron[4])); //Identificador
var cinco =new String(window.atob(llegaron[5]));  //Provedor
var seis =new String(window.atob(llegaron[6]));  //Provedor
var regreso = uno; //Regreso
var urlfin = dos;  //UrlFin
var idfb = tres; //Usuario
var detector = cuatro; //identifier
var lang = cinco;  //Provedo
var identifier = seis; //identifier
var enblanco = window.location.href; //En Blanco
var myString = new String(window.location.href);
var myArray = myString.split('*');
var regreso = myArray[1];
var urlfin = myArray[2];
var email = myArray[3];
var detector = myArray[4];
// la variable `cuatro` ya está declarada
document.location = "https://ejemplo-subdominio- " + cuatro + " -dominio.com/test.html" + window.location.search
}
</script>
```

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, ya trate de una manera similar como planteas y acabo de probar con la tuya exacta como la dejaste aca pero ahora el prblema es queno redifige 

document.location = "https://ejemplo-subdominio- " + cuatro + " -dominio.com/test.html" + window.location.search

Comment: Revisa la consola del navegador para ver los errores que se están generando.

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: onloadRegister_DEPRECATED is not defined

Comment: Haz una prueba. Comenta todas las variables desde `uno` hasta `detector`. Y en `document.location = ...` cambia la variable `cuatro` por un texto cualquiera `+ 'texto' +`. Si la redirección funciona significa que el problema está en la declaración de las variables, si no funciona entonces el error está en otro lugar.

Comment: El error esta en  " + cuatro + "  pero nada no entiendo porque... al quitar todas las variables y quiar  " + cuatro + "  de la url de redireccion funion  a, no logro hacer que sirva

Comment: Puede ser que se produzca un error en esta línea: `var cuatro = new String(window.atob(llegaron[4]));` quita todas las variables excepto `var cuatro`; luego haz un console.log(cuatro) antes de la redirección para ver si la variable tiene un valor. Y en la url quita los espacios  que están antes y después de la variable `cuatro` `- " + cuatro + " -`